# How to use Thread in cursor?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

How to use `Thread` in `Cursor`. For example we have this code :

```
cursor = sql.rawQuery(OUR QUERY..., null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                          SOME CODE....
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
```

Can we use ?

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                    do {
                          SOME CODE....
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                });
thread.start();
                }
```

Comment: Cursor is not thread-safe

Comment: More context could help. What you want to do?

Comment: I am searching on huge data. When click on the enter of software keyboard for search then i need to release the button and search box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) instead of use Thread class (avoid it when you can.)

Your Activity will implement [`LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) which contains all the callbacks you need.

Then, you need to init the CursorLoader using his `initLoader` method.

```
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
```

where it's arguments are:

```
int id, Bundle args, LoaderCallbacks<D> callback
```

> ID :
>
> A unique identifier for this loader. Can be whatever you want. Identifiers are scoped to a particular LoaderManager instance.

It's a number which you use, i used 1.

> Bundle
>
> Optional arguments to supply to the loader at construction. If a loader already exists (a new one does not need to be created), this parameter will be ignored and the last arguments continue to be used.

If you need to provide arguments, it's the right argument.

> callback
>
> Interface the LoaderManager will call to report about changes in the state of the loader. Required

It's our Activity class since it act as callback.

After this line, `onCreateLoader` is called and it will contains two arguments: `loaderID, bundle`

I think you can understand what is it.

Then it's how you could implement `onCreateLoader`

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle)
{
    /*
     * Takes action based on the ID of the Loader that's being created
     */
    switch (loaderID) {
        case LOADER_ID: // our ID!
            // Returns a new CursorLoader
            return new CursorLoader(
                        getActivity(),   // Parent activity context
                        mDataUrl,        // Table to query
                        mProjection,     // Projection to return
                        null,            // No selection clause
                        null,            // No selection arguments
                        null             // Default sort order
        );
        default:
            // An invalid id was passed in
            return null;
    }
}
```

[`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html)

When ready, `onLoadFinished` will be called with your cursor and here you go. Use it and stop.